# What use is redirectTo?

Tags: angular, routes

I understand that redirectTo redirects a route to a given component for example if you wanted to redirect the root of your app to a specific URL you might originally have this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent }, 
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
];
```

And if you wanted to change this so that the '' redirected you to the dashboard you might do this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo:'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
];
```

That clear enough, but wouldn't this be easier?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }, 
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
];
```

Unless you specifically wanted to do a redirect, maybe for SEO reasons or tracking or something then wouldn't the second option be clearer?

Comment: `redirectTo` changes your url to `whatever/dashboard`, whereas your last example would have just the url be `whatever` or `whatever/dashboard` depending on which the user types. But I guess you ask for an opinion here, which maybe isn't suitable for SO?

Comment: Thanks I hadn't realised that about the URL which might be handy for SEO, I suppose that's a reason for the option. Might be the question isn't suitable for SO - I can remove it if so.

Comment: Well I guess you'll notice what people think if you start getting downvotes :D But yeah, that was the only thing I can come up with regarding to redirectTo - to get the proper url. Maybe there are other things that I can't come up with :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no difference between the two other than the url as mentioned by `@AJT_82`.

However you would likely just end up getting a lot of duplicated code especially if there were children of that route, then you would also have to copy those children definitions. Additionally, any Route Guards which you have defined would have to be duplicated as well.

Another pain point might be if you deprecated a component, you would have to remove it from multiple places in the Routes definition

Comment: Thanks, it just struck me that the redirectTo requires more work in terms of characters typed and having to remember the path match part as well. I take your points though.

Answer (score 0):

redirect any unrecognised paths in the URL to route1:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'route1',
    loadChildren: () => import('./routes/route1/route1.module').then(m => m.Route1Module)
  },
  {
    path: 'route2',
    loadChildren: () => import('./routes/route2/route2.module').then(m => m.Route2Module)
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'route1'
  }
]
```